# I cannot remove the comma from my X axis dates in D3. Have tried .format and timeParse Advice appreciated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot seem to get this right

```
           var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.year; }), 
                 2010])
                .range([width, 0]);
```

Comment: where is the code what you tried to remove commas ? sample data ?

Comment: The data is extremely simple, a csv of year and population.
2010,17242278
2011,17673522
2012,18326450
2013,18913544
2014,19658736
2015,19658736
2016,20901780
2017,21646070
2018,22137269

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these ?

`var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d %b %Y");`

`formatTime(new Date);`

```
       or
```

`var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d %b %y");`

`formatTime(new Date);`

Comment: What was the solution ?

Comment: `var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y")`

Comment: `data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.year = parseTime(d.year);
                d.apopulation = +d.apopulation;
            });`